How to prevent users from merging contacts, but allow deleting contacts
Our business users had a specific requirement to allow certain users to retain the ability to delete records while preventing the ability to merge records. In our use case, the business had an internal process followed to merge records, and they didn't want users using the native method. Here is the solution that I came up with.
COMPONENTS:
ContactMergeHandler (Apex Class), PreventContactMerge (Apex Trigger), Allow Merge (Public Group)
trigger PreventContactMerge on Contact (before delete, after delete) {
if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete) {
    // Check if the user has permission to merge contacts
    if (!ContactMergeHandler.canMergeContacts()) {
        for (Contact contact : Trigger.old) {
            // Throw an exception if the user doesn't have permission
            contact.addError('You do not have permission to merge contacts. ' +
                    'On the contact record, please select the duplicated contact ' +
                    'that you would like to have deleted on the "Duplicate (Child) Contact" field. ' +
                    'On the account record, please select the duplicated account ' +
                    'that you would like to have deleted on the "Duplicate (obsolete) Household or Org" field.');
        }
    }
}

}
public class ContactMergeHandler {

// Method to check if the user has permission to merge contacts
public static Boolean canMergeContacts() {
    // Check if the user's profile is "System Administrator"
    if (UserInfo.getProfileId() == [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'].Id) {
        return true;
    }
    // Check if the user is in the public group "Allow_Merge"
    Group allowMergeGroup = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE DeveloperName = 'Allow_Merge' LIMIT 1];
    return allowMergeGroup != null && [SELECT COUNT() FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND GroupId = :allowMergeGroup.Id] > 0;
}

}

See above to display an error on your contact merge screen:

